# Convert Tabular format data to List format in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have the following data in my category table.

When I put select *from Category I am getting the data like this. This table has more than 10 columns

```
CategoryId CategoryName c3 c4 .....c10 
1           aaa 
2           bbb
3           ccc
...
...
```

I want to display data like this. I don't know how to prepare SQL for this.

```
CategoryId  1
CategoryName aaa
C3 
...
...
C10
CategoryId  2
CategoryName bbb
C3 
...
...
C10
CategoryId  3
CategoryName ccc
C3 
...
...
C10

...
```

Please suggest me any ideas.

Comment: The names "tabular format" and "list format" have no meaning for databases. What you describe, swapping columns and rows,  is called pivoting. At least one way to do it is using the `PIVOT` and `UNPIVOT` commands

Comment: I have more than 10 columns I want to convert this rows with two columns. I am not sure how to do unpivot for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it using `Cross Apply` like this -

```
DECLARE @OutItem TABLE 
(
    CategoryId INT,
    CategoryName varchar(10),
    c3 varchar(10)
)

INSERT INTO @OutItem
    VALUES (1,'aaa', 'c31'),
(2,'bbb', 'c32'),
(3,'ccc', 'c33')


SELECT ca.* from @OutItem
CROSS APPLY (
    VALUES ('CategoryId', CAST(CategoryId AS VARCHAR)),
        ('CategoryName', CategoryName),
        ('C3', c3)
        --, Add your 10 columns here same as above
) ca (TabCol, TabVal)
```

**Result**

```
TabCol      TabVal
===================
CategoryId    1
CategoryName  aaa
C3            c31
CategoryId    2
CategoryName  bbb
C3            c32
```

Comment: Thank you so much krishnraj